# Org-Mode - Fix LaTex export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, formatting

I've written a document in Org-mode but when exported it became like this:

1. In the image on top, I've inserted a `\bullet` but it wont show and the text is not alligned:
2. And in the image on bottom, the text is not aligned as body text, but as a list:

[image: Text not aligned and LaTex command not working]

This is the code for the first image:

```
To calculate the probability its necessary to calculate the probability of C given positive test
- P(C | Positive) = P(C) \bullet P(Positive | C)
- P(\urcorner C | Positive) = P(\urcorner C) \bullet P(Positive | -C)
```

and for the second:

```
******* Summary

It is important to always test the data after the fitting to measure the accuracy of the predictions made by the program. At least 10% of the data should be saved to test. When telling anyone the result of the predictions, tell about the accuracy of the test data.
```

Comment: Regarding the second issue, your level heading is too deep.  Unless you have an export option like `H:7`, and the export class has the appropriate definition, it will probably be interpreted as a list.

Comment: @suvayu, you're right, when I try to export just the subtree, it works as intended

Comment: @suvayu Indeed.  Interestingly enough, if you don't use upper level headings (I just pasted OP code) this is processed as a top level heading.

Comment: @VascoFerreira If you post the 2nd part as a separate question (as it should be, according to SX guidelines), I could try to give a more comprehensive response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem, you need to add `$` around the `\urcorner`s, apparently it can only appears in latex math mode.

Generally speaking, a good way to solve such problems is to export to latex instead of pdf, then compile the latex file (simply use `C-c C-c` if auctex is installed), and examine errors if any.  Of course knowing a bit about latex is recommended then.

The second part displays ok for me with the source you provided.

Comment: Also, you may want to use `\neg` rather than `\urcorner`.

Comment: If i export just the subtree it works as intended for the second problem. For the first, `$` does work, and if I also write `\begin{equation}` it also works.

Comment: What's the text before the Summary line?

Comment: It's another heading in the same level.